# C++: Is it posible to set the type of a void-pointer, variant-object or any-object in execution time?

Tags: c++, void-pointers, dereference, variant, execution-time

Void-pointer, variant-objects and any-objects are amazing because they can store many different types in the same variable. But I have a problem with them, I need to specify their type (creating and/or de-referencing them) in the execution time, is it possible?

To be more clear, for example, as far I know, to create and de-reference them I have to do this:

```
void* ptr = new int(8);
variant<int, float> var = 8;
any a = 8;
...
cout << *(int*)ptr;
cout << get<int>(var);
cout << any_cast<int>(a);
```

As you can see, in all cases the type must be "written in the code" (programming-time?). It would be excellent if that type could be determinate in the execution time. Let me dream... if, for example, we could "store a type" as an object, we could do this:

```
TYPE mi_tipo;
...
mi_tipo = int;   // or float, or char or any other...
...
void* ptr = new mi_tipo();
cout << *(mi_tipo*)ptr;
```

Something like this is possible? If not, how would you do this? I'm trying to do simulate a compiler perform, so I need an structure which can store any type of variables, and so I need an efficient way of de-reference them in execution time.

Comment: No, they are not amazing one little bit. They are a last-resort emergency weapons. You use them when your house is on fire and you are attacked by zombies. Otherwise, you want to steer as clear from them an humanly possible.

Comment: Having said that, what can you do with an object of an unknown type? Nothing at all, really. You cannot be sure new mi_tipo(); is valid. Not all types have default constructors. You cannot be sure cout << knows what to do with it. Not all objects can be printed. Try to come up with a real use case.

Answer (score 1):

C++ is a statically typed language. The type of any expression must be known at compile-time. While compile-time code can do limited forms of type computation, and even type generation to a degree, all of that exists *only* at compile-time.

Once you reach the runtime, everything has to be known. Dynamic polymorphism through base classes and `virtual` functions exist, but at the point the actual object is created, you have to know what type it is. There are techniques which can allow dynamically determining which polymorphic derived class to instantiate, but they all ultimately boil down to a bunch of conditional statements and a hard-coded (even if generated through templates) set of types.

Answer (score 0):

> Something like this is possible?

Except for `using mi_tipo = int;`, no, c++ is a *statically typed language*.

> if no, how would you do this?

Decide on an interface for your types, and enumerate all possible type and write interfaces for them to hide implementation.

```
#include <map>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <sstream>

struct AtypeInterface {
    AtypeInterface() {}
    virtual ~AtypeInterface() {}
    virtual std::string format() { throw std::runtime_error("invalid"); return ""; }
};

template<typename T>
struct Atype : AtypeInterface {
    T val;
    Atype(T val) : val(val) {}
    ~Atype() {}
    std::string format() override { 
       return std::to_string(val);
    }
};
struct AtypeVoidPointer : AtypeInterface {
    void *p;
    AtypeVoidPointer(void *p) : p(p) {}
    ~AtypeVoidPointer() {}
    std::string format() override {
        // custom behavior if needed
        if (p == NULL) {
             return "och no! the pointer is null!\n";
         } else {
             std::stringstream s;
             s << p;
             return s.str();
         }
    }
};

int main() {
   std::unique_ptr<AtypeInterface> mi_typo;
   mi_typo = std::make_unique<Atype<int>>(5);
   std::cout << mi_typo->format() << '\n';
}
```

Such design looks "good enough".

Answer (score -2):

> Something like this is possible?

Yes, but you need to store the type information yourself somehow. There is no reflection in C++ so far, static or otherwise.

There are also tricks around RTTI (Run-Time Type Information), but I wouldn't recommend those.

> how would you do this?

Use a tag to carry which type is inside, for instance, an `enum class`.

Otherwise, use standard or third-party solutions that do this for you, like `std::variant`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question as asked. `std::variant` and `std::any` already contain this information. There is no need to add your own version of it.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. "*This has nothing to do with the question as asked*" The question is about whether C++ has reflection support/dynamic typing. "*std::variant and std::any already contain this information*" The answers mentions this. "*There is no need to add your own version of it.*" There are several reasons why you would like to avoid `std::variant` (bad codegen, heavy on compile times, no control over the tag...). As for `std::any`, it is usually a design smell to begin with.

Comment: So suggest to OP to implement their own specialised tagged union because the std::variant has bad performance and other characteristics. That's an extraordinary claim that would have required an extraordinary proof---if it were relevant, that is. OP's question is not about implementing a tagged union. It is about using *types* as if they were *values*. Tagged unions are just a red herring.

Comment: The answer doesn't suggest that, so read it again. Even if it did, it wouldn't be an extraordinary claim: most std facilities are not optimal at all, and that is a feature, not a bug. The extraordinary claim is the opposite. This answer is not about implementing tagged unions either.

Comment: Then I don't understand what it *is* about. "you need to store the type information yourself somehow". "Use a tag to carry which type is inside". I cannot see anything but an implementation of a tagged union in there, however hard I try.